# Admin Config page for my module is empty

Tags: 7

I created a module (namely, "casabaca_s3s") and set a configure entry in the casabaca_s3s.info file:

`configure = admin/config/content/casabaca_s3s`

Now my "Configure" appears in the module.

Then, i added, in my casabaca_s3s.module file, the following code:

And my hook:

```
function casabaca_s3s_menu()
{
    return array(
        'admin/config/content/casabaca_s3s' => array(
            'title' => 'Casabaca',
            'description' => 'Configuración de Casabaca',
            'page_callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page_arguments' => array('casabaca_s3s_admin'),
            'access arguments' => array('administer casabaca_s3s pages'),
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        ),
    );
}
```

And my handler for the hook:

```
function casabaca_s3s_admin() {
    return system_settings_form(array(
        'casabaca_s3s_modelcosts' => array(
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#title' => t('Modelos y kilometrajes'),
            '#description' => t("Archivo .csv con el contenido de la tabla de precios según modelo y kilometraje"),
            '#required' => true,
            '#upload_validators' => array(
                'file_validate_extensions' => array(0 => 'csv'),
                'file_validate_size' => array(32*1024*1024),
            ),
        ),
        'casabaca_s3s_extracosts' => array(
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#title' => t('Costos de servicios adicionales'),
            '#description' => t("Archivo .csv con el contenido de la tabla de precios de servicios extra"),
            '#required' => true,
            '#upload_validators' => array(
                'file_validate_extensions' => array(0 => 'csv'),
                'file_validate_size' => array(32*1024*1024),
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

**Problem**: When I click "Configure" button in module listing (the one with the gear), it redirects to admin/config/content/casabaca_s3s, but that page is empty, showing standard message: "No tiene ningún elemento administrativo." (trans. You have no administrative elements). What am I missing to display the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'page_callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page_arguments' => array('casabaca_s3s_admin'),
```

needs to be

```
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('casabaca_s3s_admin'),
```

(underscores removed from array keys)

Comment: Quick and clean :D. Accepting in 2 minutes...